# General way of showing linear dependence and independence

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

> Let the vectors $v_1 , v_2 , v_3$ be in $R^n$ ($ n \geq 3$) , and assume that these vectors are not zero.
>
> assuming that the sets {${v_1 , v_2}$} , {${v_2 , v_3}$} and {${v_1 , v_3}$} are linearly independent , then does the set {${v_1 , v_2 , v_3}$} have to be independent as well?

My solution:

According to the information given that {${v_1 , v_2}$} , {${v_2 , v_3}$} and {${v_1 , v_3}$} are linearly independent we get that

1. $x_1 \cdot v_1+x_2 \cdot v_2=0$ $x_1 ,x_2 = 0$
2. $x_2 \cdot v_2+x_3 \cdot v_3=0$ $x_2 ,x_3 = 0$
3. $x_3 \cdot v_3+x_1 \cdot v_1=0$ $x_3 ,x_1 = 0$

now we need to check if the set {${v_1 , v_2 , v_3}$} is independent , I did this by  counterexample.

assume n=3 and $v_1=$ {$1,0,0$} , $v_2=$ {$0,1,0$} and $v_3=$ {$1,1,0$} then its obvious that {${v_1 , v_2}$} , {${v_2 , v_3}$} and {${v_1 , v_3}$} are linearly independent but {${v_1 , v_2 , v_3}$} is dependent because $v_1 +v_2 = v_3$.

What I mean by general proof is I rather prove this by a way without a countrexample with numbers as I believe it is harder to always find numbers that satisfy what we are looking for , this is what I also tried for the "general" proof.

if the set {${v_1 , v_2 , v_3}$} is dependent then $x_1 \cdot v_1+x_2 \cdot v_2 +x_3 \cdot v_3=0$ while $x_1 , x_2 , x_3$ are different than zero. according to the given information $x_2 \cdot v_2+x_3 \cdot v_3=0$ then I used that to do this $x_1 \cdot v_1+x_2 \cdot v_2 +x_3 \cdot v_3=x_2 \cdot v_2 +x_3 \cdot v_3$ and we $x_1 \cdot v_1 = x_2 \cdot v_2 +x_3 \cdot v_3 $ then we get that it is linearly dependent.. **but this way seemed very wrong and uncertain to me**  is it possible to do this with a general proof? or counterexample is the only way?
Thank you!

Comment: In what way do you want to make your proof more general? Is it just about the dimension? Then the same example works when you add more zeros. And otherwise providing a counterexample is the standard way to show that a statement of the form "for every $x$: something" is not true.

Comment: @OnDragi This is what I meant a proof of "for every x:something" but if you say it is not true or possible then you answered my question

Comment: The negation is "exists $x$: not something" -- providing a concrete $x$ proves that there exists one.

Comment: You can provide a more general example though, if you insist. If $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is linearly independent, then so is $\{v_1,v_1+v_2\}$ and $\{v_2, v_1+v_2\}$, so the triplet $\{v_1,v_2,v_1+v_2\}$ satisfies your assumption, but is clearly a linearly dependent set.

Comment: @OnDragi thank you! is this because if we have an dependent subset set then the set is also dependent? and if we have a set that is independent then every subset of it is also independent? sorry for the questions I am struggling to understand what you mean

Comment: Both statements you say are true. It seems to me it would help you to imagine the things geometrically to get the right intuition. A set of $k$ vectors is linearly independent iff they span a $k$-dimensional space, so for example in $R^3$, two vectors are independent iff they span a plane. It's easy to see that if you take some combination of two such vectors, you now have three vectors such that every pair still spans the same plane, but all three together are still in that plane and don't span the whole $R^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$v_1=(1,0,0),v_2=(0,1,0), v_3=(1,1,0)$ is a simple counter-example in $\mathbb R^{3}$. For  $\mathbb R^{n}$ you can make an obvious modification